Using maven to build dependencies within my java project
(I've been googling and searching for several days now.  Time to ask humans.)
I've got a java project that I'm building with command-line maven.
The project has several dependencies to other open-source code.
For policy reasons, I'd like to include the source code to these dependencies under my project src directory and have maven build them from source rather than using pre-built jars that are downloaded from the InterWebs.  That way, we can safely assure users that all the source is built and thus they know what they are getting.
I can't figure out how to do this in maven.  When I drop the dependency sources into my src/main/java/ org,com,mil subdirs, I get java compile errors because those other projects are building different java packages.
Is this possible to do?  Any pointers?
More details.  Right now, maven is pulling dependencies from its central repo and storing the jars locally. Here is a dependency tree:
[INFO] com.openathena:core:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.adobe.xmp:xmpcore:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20240303:compile
[INFO] +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.81:compile
[INFO] +- mil.nga:mgrs:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- mil.nga:grid:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- mil.nga:sf:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- mil.nga:color:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- mil.nga:tiff:jar:3.0.0:compile

I'm not concerned about the junit and jcommander dependencies as those are for java Apps and for a standalone jar, not a big deal.
But I'd like to be able to have these jars built locally instead of linked.
Thank you,
Bobby

First you have to consider that each of your dependencies can have it's own dependencies... furthermore those pre built things are build by different tools... From where do you consume those pre-built jars ? Central repository I assume? There you can look up the locations... furthermore if you don't trust the pre-built jars? What about the build tool you are using? What about that? So you have to start a whole bootstrap from scratch ? https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.9.7/ (https://github.com/apache/maven) ... That is a real hard problem to solve...

Questions in [so] need to be specific. Provide a [mre].

Poor title. Did not reflect your real question.

This is rather non-trivial.
Usually, you cannot just build the pure sources of open source projects. You also need the POMs (if they have any, and are not build with Gradle, Ant ,...) and maybe further configuration.
So best you can do is probably (for every such open source project):

Find the project on GitHub, GitLab or alike.
Check it out from there and build it according to the documentation (if there is any).
Reference the JAR that you built in you original project.

If you cannot find the project on GitHub or if you cannot figure out how to build it, then there is probably not much more you can do.

Thank you.  I'm considering that.  I could modify my project/pom to include a lib dir and drop jars into it.  I could then also download each of those dependencies from github and build them.  I'd love to avoid this but can certainly do it.

Or they can use the multi “module” feature of Maven to create a mini-project for each dependency, all enclosed within the main project.

I managed to get the various open source libraries to compile under my own src directory tree so I sorta avoided really solving the problem.  I first used git to clone the repo and then when into the src/main/java subdir and copied the code into my own repo.  My maven pom.xml then compiled the code just fine.
I left the external dependencies for Junit and jcommander as they are not integral to the project.  Now, when someone clones and builds the code, they'll be able to audit and then build everything from scratch.
Bobby
